# Jquery Validation Remote Check Unique Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I wanted to post this online because I have been searching for days on this JQuery Remote validation issue. I cannot get it to work. I think my PHP code is correct as I have test the URL with a query in the URL and it returns false and true depending on with the recordset count is one or more

**This is my Jquery Validate Code:**

```
// validate form and submit
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("#myform").validate({
rules: {
ord_ref: {
required: true,
minlength: 12,
remote: "check_ord_ref.php"
},
messages: {
ord_ref: {
remote: "Order Number Does Not Exist"
}
}
}
});
});
```

**This is my PHP code for the remote page "check_ord_ref.php"**

```
$colname_rscheck_ord_ref = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['ord_ref'])) {
  $colname_rscheck_ord_ref = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['ord_ref'] : addslashes($_GET['ord_ref']);
}
mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_rscheck_ord_ref = sprintf("SELECT ref_ord FROM orders WHERE ref_ord = '%s'", $colname_rscheck_ord_ref);
$rscheck_ord_ref = mysql_query($query_rscheck_ord_ref, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rscheck_ord_ref = mysql_fetch_assoc($rscheck_ord_ref);
$totalRows_rscheck_ord_ref = mysql_num_rows($rscheck_ord_ref);
if($totalRows_rscheck_ord_ref < 0){
        $valid = 'false';
        } else {
        $valid = 'true';

         }
         echo $valid;
```

**Please someone can you help solve the puzzle for myself and anyone else having issues**

1. Using JQuery 1.5.2min
2. Validates OK without remote function

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I'm no PHP expert, but I do know that jQuery Validate expects the following result from a remote validation method:

> The response is **evaluated as JSON** and must be true for valid elements,
>   and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements

Sending down `"true"` or `"false"` (note the quotation marks) is going to result in the value being parsed as the error message instead of being evaluated as a boolean primitive.

Back to the PHP part, I *think* you should probably use `json_encode` with a boolean primitive. I'm not quite sure the way to do this in PHP, but I believe it would be something like this:

```
$colname_rscheck_ord_ref = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['ord_ref'])) {
  $colname_rscheck_ord_ref = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? $_GET['ord_ref'] : addslashes($_GET['ord_ref']);
}

mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);
$query_rscheck_ord_ref = sprintf("SELECT ref_ord FROM orders WHERE ref_ord = '%s'", $colname_rscheck_ord_ref);
$rscheck_ord_ref = mysql_query($query_rscheck_ord_ref, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rscheck_ord_ref = mysql_fetch_assoc($rscheck_ord_ref);
$totalRows_rscheck_ord_ref = mysql_num_rows($rscheck_ord_ref);

if($totalRows_rscheck_ord_ref < 0){
    $valid = false; // <-- Note the use of a boolean primitive.
} else {
    $valid = true;
}

echo json_encode($valid);
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your post and time. I have read on other forums about using the json_encode to return the response. I have changed it on my PHP code but it still does not work.

Comment: @ZeePee: Are you using a boolean primitive? i.e. `true` instead of `"true"`

Comment: Hi I have tried both this is the current code: echo false; } else { echo true; } I have also tried  $valid = false;  } else {     $valid = true; }  echo json_encode($valid);

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be plaguing remote validation scripters and the jQuery documentation on the matter is clearly lacking.

I notice you are using jQuery 1.5.2:  from what I understand (and found from experience) you must use the jQuery callback that is sent to the remote script with $_REQUEST with versions after 1.4, AND jQuery is expecting "true" or "false" as a STRING.  Here is an example, confirmed working on multiple forms (I'm using jQuery 1.7.1):

```
if($totalRows_rscheck_ord_ref < 0){
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $valid = 'false'; //    <---yes, Validate is expecting a string
    $result = $_REQUEST['callback'].'('.$check.')';
    echo $result;
} else {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $valid = 'true'; //    <---yes, Validate is expecting a string
    $result = $_REQUEST['callback'].'('.$check.')';
    echo $result;
}
```

I found this answer [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validation-plugin-remote-validation-problem-locks-up) (in the answers section), randomly, and have since stopped pulling out my hair.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Andrew Whitaker's response above, I must stress that you are sure that the response is strictly JSON and that there are no other content types being returned. I was having the same issue with my script, and everything appeared to be set properly - including using `json_encode()`. After some troubleshooting with Firebug's NET tab, I was able to determine that PHP notices were being sent back to the browser converting the data from JSON to text/html. After I turned the errors off, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

//check_validate.php

```
<?php

// some logic here

echo json_encode(true);
?>
```

Comment: And how should this be used? Currently this snippet adds little to no value to the answers given.